# Checking my DVD's current reading speed

Tags: dvd

I use Linux Mint 18.2. I learned how to change the speed of my DVD drive on this page:

https://www.hecticgeek.com/change-optical-disc-drive-speed-ubuntu-linux/

I would write

> eject -x 4

to set the speed to "4".

**However, how do I check what my current speed is?** I can't find any terminal commands to print this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove any disks from your CD/DVD drive.

Open your terminal and enter:

```
wodim -prcap
```

You should get outputs similar to:

```
  Maximum read  speed:  8468 kB/s (CD  48x, DVD  6x)
  Current read  speed:  8468 kB/s (CD  48x, DVD  6x)
  Maximum write speed:  8468 kB/s (CD  48x, DVD  6x)
  Current write speed:  8468 kB/s (CD  48x, DVD  6x)
```

You can also use:

```
cdrecord -prcap
```